# Can I use another person's credit card to register my Android Developer account?

Tags: android, google-play, credit-card

I want to register for a developer account on Google but unfortunately, I don't have a credit card yet, nor will I get one any time soon. I'm thinking of borrowing one from friends or relatives and using it to pay the $25 fee and then I'd pay my friend/relative that amount physically instead. Is this plausible? Are there any implications? I don't plan on selling paid apps, I just want to publish the freeware that I make.

Comment: This is not an SO question... This should be more targeted to Google's FAQ.

Comment: Yes, it is only used by Google for charging registration fee, nothing to do with your Developer Console account setup. If you decide to sell app later, Google will ask for your bank account details.

Comment: Well this is a developer discussion site so I thought I could ask it here to get the insights of fellow developers.

Comment: @Propeller could you please explain what you did to use another person's credit card to pay the registration fee? I tried to sign up for Google Play Publisher account using my account but I also have to pay using my account (I can't change the account). What did you do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It shouldn't be a problem unless the account details are linked to card for validation. As you don't have a credit/debit card I'm assuming you are under 18. You should note the following:

1.4 In order to use Google Play you must be 13 years of age or older. If you are between 13 and 18 years of age, you must have your parent or legal guardian’s permission to use Google Play.

Comment: Nah, I'm over 18. It's just that getting a credit card here in our country is much of a hassle. BTW, what did you mean by "unless the account details are linked to card for validation" ?

Comment: I'm sure it means credit or debit card. Is getting a debit card a hassle too? In the UK you can get one in a matter of minutes with some identification and a couple of quid.

What I meant by validation was that in some cases, the users name/address must link up with the card owner.

Comment: I think debit card is fairly easy but AFAIK, they only accept credit cards here.. Thanks for the answer though!

Comment: I have kindof similar problem. I have a credit card type that's not accepted by Wallet. I was wondering if Google would disable my Play Developer Console account in case I had a friend to do the payment and then remove his card from Wallet. Does anyone have an idea about this? Currently, I can't afford switching to another card.